# Unity3D (2D) Grid Based path following and line drawing system not working

Tags: c#, path, controller, unity-game-engine, grid-layout

I'm currently working on a set of scripts. The collective purpose of these scripts is to create a controller object that, upon the user clicking on an object, will check if the object is a GridCell object then add it to a list of positions; the list of positions will be followed by the controller as a path.

A secondary effect of the script is that it should draw a line representing the path created by the list of positions. There are five different scripts in the entire project, here they are:

**GridController.cs** (Primary script)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GridController : MonoBehaviour {

    private RaycastHit rayhit;
    public Path controllerPath;
    public GLLineController lineController;
    public bool playerTransforming = false;

    public Vector2 currentTarget = Path.VECTORNULL;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        controllerPath = new Path();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (RaycastHitGridcell(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out this.rayhit))
            {
                Vector2 tempRayhitV = new Vector2(rayhit.transform.position.x, rayhit.transform.position.y);
                controllerPath.Add(tempRayhitV);
                if (controllerPath.PathList2D.Count < 1)
                {
                    lineController.lineList.Add(new Line(transform.position,
                        new Vector3(tempRayhitV.x, tempRayhitV.y),
                        Screen.width,
                        Screen.height,
                        Camera.main,
                        false));
                }
                else
                {
                    Vector2 lastInLineList =  controllerPath.PathList2D[controllerPath.PathList2D.Count - 1];
                    lineController.lineList.Add(new Line(new Vector3(lastInLineList.x, lastInLineList.y),
                        new Vector3(tempRayhitV.x, tempRayhitV.y),
                        Screen.width,
                        Screen.height,
                        Camera.main,
                        false));
                }
            }
        }

        #region tryNext

        /*Vector2 nv2;
        if (!playerTransforming && controllerPath.TryNext(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), out nv2, out this.playerTransforming))
        {
            this.transform.Translate(nv2.x, nv2.y, 0f);
        }*/
        if (!playerTransforming && controllerPath.PathList2D.Count > 1)
        {
            Vector2 nv2 = controllerPath.Next();
            if (nv2 != Path.VECTORNULL)
            {
                playerTransforming = true;
                currentTarget = nv2;
                this.transform.Translate(new Vector3(nv2.x, nv2.y, 0f));
            }
        }

        if (currentTarget != Path.VECTORNULL && (Mathf2.Approximately(currentTarget.x, transform.position.x, 0.001f) &&
            Mathf2.Approximately(currentTarget.y, transform.position.y, 0.001f)))
        {
            playerTransforming = false;
            currentTarget = Path.VECTORNULL;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public static bool RaycastHitGridcell(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        RaycastHit tHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out tHit))
        {
            if (tHit.transform.gameObject.tag == "GridCell")
            {
                hit = tHit;
                return true;
            }
        }
        hit = tHit;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Path.cs** (Represents a list of positions to follow)

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Path {

    /// <summary>
    /// List that represents a path of positions.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Vector2> PathList2D = new List<Vector2>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate a constant variable that stores the default NULL value for a vector2 x value.
    /// </summary>
    public const float VECTORNULL_X = float.NaN;
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate a constant variable that stores the default NULL value for a vector2 y value.
    /// </summary>
    public const float VECTORNULL_Y = float.NaN;
    public static Vector2 VECTORNULL_V2
    {
        get { return new Vector2(VECTORNULL_X, VECTORNULL_Y); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an object to the end of the vector2 list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">Object to add.</param>
    public void Add(Vector2 position)
    {
        PathList2D.Add(position);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove a specific object from the vector2 list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">Object to remove.</param>
    public void Remove(Vector2 position)
    {
        PathList2D.Remove(position);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove an object at a specified index within the vector2 list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Indext to remove the object at.</param>
    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        PathList2D.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove the current position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>VECTORNULL if path isn't long enough. The next position if the path is long enough.</returns>
    public Vector2 Next()
    {
        if (PathList2D.Count < 1)
            return VECTORNULL_V2;
        Vector2 nvt = PathList2D[0];
        PathList2D.RemoveAt(0);
        return nvt;
    }
}

public class SpecialVector2
{
    private float _X, _Y;
    public float X
    {
        get { return (Null ? float.NaN : _X); }
        set { _X = value; }
    }
    public float Y
    {
        get { return (Null ? float.NaN : _Y); }
        set { _Y = value; }
    }

    public bool Null = false;

    public SpecialVector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this._X = x;
        this._Y = y;
    }

    public SpecialVector2(bool nullFlag)
    {
        this.Null = nullFlag;
    }

    public static SpecialVector2 TrueNull()
    {
        return new SpecialVector2(true);
    }
}
```

**Line.cs** (Object that represents the vectors for a GL line)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Line {
    public Vector3 StartingVertex;
    public Vector3 EndingVertex;

    public Line(Vector3 starting, Vector3 ending, int xMax, int yMax, Camera viewport, bool vpCompatible = true)
    {
        if (!vpCompatible)
        {
            StartingVertex = new Vector3((starting.x - viewport.transform.position.x) / (float)xMax,
                (starting.y - viewport.transform.position.y) / (float)yMax,
                0);

            EndingVertex = new Vector3((ending.x - viewport.transform.position.x) / (float)xMax,
                (ending.y - viewport.transform.position.y) / (float)yMax,
                0);
        }
        else
        {
            StartingVertex = starting;
            EndingVertex = ending;
        }
    }
}
```

**GLLineController.cs** (Script that controls the post rendering of GL lines.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GLLineController : MonoBehaviour {

    /// <summary>
    /// Material to pass over the line.
    /// </summary>
    private Material mat;
    /// <summary>
    /// List of line objects that will represent the vectors for the GL lines.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Line> lineList = new List<Line>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CreateLineMaterial();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign a basic material pass to the mat field.
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateLineMaterial()
    {
        if (!mat)
        {
            mat = new Material("Shader \"Lines/Colored Blended\" {" +
                    "SubShader { Pass { " +
                    "    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha " +
                    "    ZWrite Off Cull Off Fog { Mode Off } " +
                    "    BindChannels {" +
                    "      Bind \"vertex\", vertex Bind \"color\", color }" +
                    "} } }");
            mat.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
            mat.shader.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        GL.PushMatrix();
        mat.SetPass(0);
        GL.LoadOrtho();
        GL.Begin(GL.LINES);

        GL.Color(Color.white);

        foreach (Line l in lineList)
        {
            GL.Vertex(l.StartingVertex);
            GL.Vertex(l.EndingVertex);
        }

        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Theoretically, these scripts should work semi-perfectly in union, but they don't work at all from what i can tell.

Does anybody have a better way to go about this? Otherwise, does anybody know where my error(s) is/are?

Thank you!
-Tristen H.

Comment: You should really zero in on what the problem is (walls of code are hard for S.O. to cope with). What is the minimum set of functions that create your problem?

Comment: @NathanielFord I don't know where the error is. For the past week ive been debugging and searching for the source of the problem and i have no idea where it is. (Unity doesn't allow for step-into debugging, sadly). Pretty much all of the code ive posted is relevant.    

**Edit:** I've concluded that the Mathf2.cs object is not required. Thus, i removed it.